# MySQL REGEXP to match word list and any number of spaces

Tags: mysql, regex

For example I want the query below to match the description field with value "I am in east of silicon valley."

```
select * from t1 where descriptions regexp '(east|silicon|valley){3}()*';
```

Comment: Take a look at fulltext searches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select * from t1 where descriptions regexp '((east|silicon|valley).*){3}()*';
```